# How to show 404 error in Joomla, if a product is not published or unpublished

Tags: php, joomla, error-handling

We have a product listing page, how to show 404 error where in if the product is not published in Joomla 2.5. Here v_status in database is the publishing value, 0 as not published and 1 as published

```
function loadProduct($vid){
$database =& JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "Select *, (select prod_name from #__usedcar_products where prod_id=v.v_prod_id) as prod_name from #__usedcar_variants AS v Where v.v_status='1' and v.v_id = '".$vid."'";
$database->setQuery($sql);
$rows = $database->loadObjectList();
return $rows[0];

   if(v_status=0) {
       JError::raiseError(404, JText::_("Product Not Found"));
            return;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JError::raiseError(404, "Message");
```

OR

```
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
//Do something here
```

`v_status=0` this means you are assigning `v_status` to `0`.

`v_status == 0` it should be like this

Comment: Thanks Moeed. But i thinks there is something wrong in my code above as have mentioned - if(v_status=0) { JError::raiseError(404, JText::_("Product Not Found")); return;   } . But page is not loading